# From code straight to ER diagram

Tags: sql, erd

Is there a way for me to check my written sql code to see if the ER diagram matches? So like from:

```
         CREATE TABLE Teaches( ssn INT ()
                               ....
                               ....
          )
```

straight to an ER diagram?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://www.visual-paradigm.com/features/database-design-with-erd-tools/

Answer (score 0):

ER diagrams in the academic form are the **conceptual model of the database**, they are not directly related to SQL. however, there are some tools which can forward and reverse engineer between a database design (in some form) and an existing database. If you use MySql then you can try [Mysql Workbench](https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/) for such task.